# Html.DisplayNameFor List vs IEnumerable in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am implementing the [PaginatedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1) from the tutorial.

It works. My issue if that if I defined the `@model` as an `IEnumerable` in my Razor page I can do this:

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomerDisplayViewModel>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
```

If I define `@model` as `List`, the `@Html.DisplayNameFor` helper works differently, and I have to call it like this:

```
@model List<CustomerDisplayViewModel>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().LastName)
```

Difference being that in the first call the expression cast model to be `CustomerDisplayViewModel` and in the second it is a `List<CustomerDisplayViewModel>`.

The issue is caused by the compiler prefering to cast the call to

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<TModel> 
string DisplayNameFor<TResult>(Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression);
```

Instead of

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperDisplayNameExtensions
public static string DisplayNameFor<TModelItem, TResult>(
this IHtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModelItem>> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModelItem, TResult>> expression);
```

I know I can use my workaround (`@Html.DisplayNameFor( model => model.First().LastName)`) but it doesn't feel correct.

**Is there a way to cast the call or maybe generating my own extension that calls the IEnumerable extension (I would prefer to not create an extension from scratch, this call should work exactly as the IEnumerable).** I can create the extension method with List<>, however, I  haven't been able to cast it.

```
 public static string DisplayNameFor<TModelItem, TResult>
            (this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<List<TModelItem>> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModelItem, TResult>> expression)
        {
            var castHelper = --- somehow cast helper to IHtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModelItem>
            return castHelper.DisplayNameFor(expression);
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason you want to use List over IEnumerable in this case?

Comment: What's your purpose btw-- do you just need to display a label for each of the records in your List?

Comment: I simplified my sample. I want to use PaginatedList in the view. IEnumerable doesn't fit the bill - I need properties from PaginatedList. BTW: even if I could interchange with IEnumerable (which I can't), I feel like there should be a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the generic parameter `TModel` of `IHtmlHelper` is **not [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)**. Basically, you cannot do this:

```
IHtmlHelper<List<CustomerDisplayViewModel>> helperList = new HtmlHelper<List<CustomerDisplayViewModel>(...);

IHtmlHelper<IEnumerable<CustomerDisplayViewModel>> helperIEnumerable = helperList;
// the above line is an error
```

---

However, you can do that with `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<int> intList = new List<int>();
IEnumerable<object> objList = intList; // no error
```

This is because `IEnumerable` is declared like this:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable { .. }
```

Note the `out` keyword which specifies that the generic parameter `T` is covariant.
Had `IHtmlHelper<TModel>` been declared like this in the framework:

```
interface IHtmlHelper<out TModel> { .. }
```

your code would have worked.

---

Despite this, you can still use [`Html.DisplayNameForInnerType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper-1.displaynameforinnertype?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to get the display name(ASP.NET Core only) in such cases:

```
@model PaginatedList<CustomerDisplayViewModel>
...
@Html.DisplayNameForInnerType((CustomerDisplayViewModel c) => c.LastName)
```

Note that you have to explicitly specify the type of the lambda expression parameter.(`CustomerDisplayViewModel c`).